# Can't Delete/Edit Files on SD Card

Tags: windows-10, dell-inspiron, card-reader

I have a Dell laptop (Inspiron 15 5559) and I can't Edit/Delete from the sd card reader.

I've moved the readonly switch to both places, I've tried different cards and is the same, what could be wrong?

Comment: Is it posible that you have a security software/antivir preventing you from writing to such devices or via a Group policy?
@Tetsujin Dont think it is a duplicate since he has tried different cards.

Comment: Do the cards read OK in other computers? Basically, it sounds as though you've proved there is something wrong with the card reader on your computer.

Comment: Yes they do, and that is my fear bro, to have problems with the internal reader